# Displaying post format icon next to the title in recent posts

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, icons

I am creating a theme from scratch, and it's going quite well so far, but I've been wondering if there is a way to display the post format (e.g. standard post, audio, video, image etc.) icon next to a post title when displaying the list of recent posts?

I would like the readers to know right away what kind of post they are about to read / listen to / see..

I know it's possible to format whole posts based on their format, but couldn't find anything regarding the links to them in a widget. I'm thinking it should be possible—if you can get the titles, why couldn't you get the formats and their icons as well?

There definitely IS a way to do it .. somehow, because it's exactly what [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/recent-posts-video-icon) does. However, it does it only for one post format, but how to add icons for all of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [possible](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_format). Adding

```
<?php $format = get_post_format(); ?>
```

in the loop will return the format of the post. e.g.

```
<?php echo 'The post format is: ' . get_post_format(); ?>
```

will return: `The post format is: video`. If the post format is the default one, it will return `null`.

If you place the `get_post_format()` beside the post title, it should display what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Howli doesn't answer the icon question. I did my homework and wrote some code but if my posts are paginated I don't know how to load the image since its URL changes every time you turn the page.   [Here is how it looks the first page of (paginated) post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFMQ4.jpg)

It's in Spanish but you'll get the idea. After page 1 image link is broken since the png's url changes with pagination and I haven't solved that yet.